# Populate combo box based on criteria with excel vba

Tags: excel, vba, combobox, foreach, auto-populate

PLEASE HELP! I need this done by the end of the day TODAY (11/4/13)!!!
I've been trying to figure out this problem in a number of different ways all day, and I can't figure it out. Help needed!

I have a series of userforms that the user uses to select certain criteria that reads the data from the spreadsheet to ultimately produce a list of information in a final listbox userform. In one userform (ScoreRange), the user is asked to type in two numbers into two separate listboxes (tbScore1 and tbScore2), and then once they enter the two scores and click a command button labeled "OK", the next userform opens with a combobox (cbName), which I would like to have it populated with names from column A whose corresponding score in column E falls within the user's selected score range. I want it to do this loop search through rows 2-401. Currently, the combobox is blank when it is opened up; it is not populating correctly. Here is the current code that I have. I should mention that the ScoreRange userform is still open (it has not been unloaded yet).

```
   Private Sub UserForm_Activate() 
   Dim i as Long
     For i = 2 To 401
     If Range("E" & i).Value >= ScoreRange.tbScore1.Value And Range("E" & i).Value <= ScoreRange.tbScore2.Value Then
     Me.cbName.AddItem Range("A" & i).Value
     End if
     Next i
         End Sub
```

Comment: Take out `On Error Resume Next` and I suspect you will find your error immediately (also add `Option Explicit` to the top of your module).

Comment: I removed "On Error Resume Next" and there are no errors when I run the code, but the combobox is empty. So, that doesn't solve my problem. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Never mind, everyone. I finally decided that the only efficient way to do this was to use autofilters. Here is the final code that I used, for those who are interested.

```
     Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
      Dim wksheet1 As Worksheet
      Set wksheet1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
      Dim LR As Long
      LR = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
      Dim cbRange As Range

    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table2").Range.AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:= _
    ">=" & tbScore1.Value, Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=" & tbScore2.ValueActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table2").Range.AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:= _
    ">=" & tbScore1.Value, Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=" & tbScore2.Value

      For Each cbRange In Range("A2:A" & LR).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
      Me.cbName.AddItem cbRange.Value
          Next cbRange

    ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False
    ActiveSheet.ShowAllData


      End Sub
```